# Maintain data consistency between producer and consumer in KAFKA

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, apache-kafka

I have a java, springboot project where I am using Kafka for asynchronous communication. have a Kafka producer, which executes some logic and saves the record to the db. Then, it raises an event which is consumed by a consumer which in turn indexes the record on the elastic search.

But, if some exception occurs while indexing, there will be inconsistency between the data in db and elastic search.

Is there a way given by KAFKA to maintain data consistency in these scenarios? Or, do I need to devise a way myself?

Went through the kafka documentation but could not find anything helpful.

Comment: In my opinion in this case you have to do it with `Saga design pattern`. The Saga design pattern is a way to manage data consistency across microservices in distributed transaction scenarios.